# What does "!)V)MSZJUgX_" mean in Stack API filter?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I was looking into Stack API doc and found the following API call.

`https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#order=desc&min=1&sort=votes&filter=!)V)MSZJUgX_&site=stackoverflow&run=true`

I understand all parts but `filter=!)V)MSZJUgX_`. Apparently this call returns the same result as `filter=total` so I assume that `!)V)MSZJUgX_` may be equal to `total`. But how?

Comment: This should probably be on [meta].

Comment: Impressive. After just 3 minutes (!) google found **this** question when searching for this string. Beyond that, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96388/40774 , but I cannot derive an answer from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!)V)MSZJUgX_` is a unique ID for a custom, [Stack Exchange, API filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).

The filter controls what the Stack Exchange API returns -- to reduce bandwidth and increase speed by not returning unwanted properties. See [the doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) for more info.

You can see what the filter (potentially) returns by using [the `/filters/{filters}` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-filter).

In this particular case, `!)V)MSZJUgX_` just returns [the `.total` property](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-filter#filters=!)V)MSZJUgX_&filter=default&run=true).  That is, it just returns the total number of comments on the site -- when used with [the query shown in the question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#order=desc&min=1&sort=votes&filter=!)V)MSZJUgX_&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

---

For more information about creating custom filters, see the above links, plus:

- [This answer on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653).
- Plus several other [questions on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/filter).
- Plus even [questions on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bapi%5D%20filter).

Comment: Darn, I was hoping there'd be more specific instructions here, since I can't create a [working] filter at all. (My question [elsewhere](https://stackapps.com/q/7829/50270).)

Comment: @ashleedawg, updated but only tangentially related.  I'll get to your question in a bit (no promises).

Comment: Thanks - I've read the docs and a number of questions; I'm probably missing something silly.